# How to make proportional signs on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, maps

I usually use the proportional circles extension of QGIS but I need to have proportional pork or pigs according to the number of pigs per exploitations (it's a map about agriculture). 
How do I do that ?

Answer (score 5):

In order to symbolize the pigs proportionally, you need to do the following, but I will use (cat) because I don't have a symbol for pig:

[image]

1. Open `layer properties -> Style -> Select Graduated`
2. Select the `Column` that contains the number of pigs
3. Click on Symbol to Change it
4. Select point marker
5. From the drop-down menu -> `Select SVG marker`
6. If you can find a symbol for a pig, then select it, but here I selected a cat symbol
7. Change the `Method` from `Color` to `Size`, as you can see below:

[image]

8. Click on `Classify`. It will be classified based on size not color.
9. Here is the output:

[image]